# Are there any free tools to measure web project's performance, security and other standards?

Tags: web-applications, coding-standards, code-security

Are there any open-source tools to measure the standard of a web application project? I want to verify my project for:

- Possible security leaks (SQL Injection etc.)
- Performance
- Stability (in high concurrent environment)

and other quality metrics.

Comment: Depending on the language you are coding in there are many static code analysis tools that will look over your code and warn you of issues like security, compliance, and a lot more. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many tools, some of them are free.

For Performance testing you can use the YSlow browser plugin which gives you a good overview to start with. Apache [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) would allow for far more tests with heavy load and if you install it on several machines could test for concurrency. It's scriptable, so you could write very complex user interactions. I haven't used it for some time now, but remember, that it allowed for a lot of options how to test your website.
Other alternatives are: [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [Watir](http://watir.com/), [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/)

[WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) works in it's free version similar to YSlow, but runs from several servers worldwide and has a few more settings. I don't know, what the payed variant offers, but maybe worth a look.

For SQL Injection there are some tools like [NetSparker](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/) which can run tests. I didn't use this one by now, but it looks promising.

[Exploit-Me](http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/) is a set of tools for Firefox that can test against several vulnerabilities.